# How do I properly display chemical compounds within \equation? (mhchem won't do what I need)

Tags: equations, mhchem

I am trying to programmatically convert a very large number of documents that have chemical compounds represented within math equations.  I am converting from some flavor of RUNOFF (I think..it isn't well documented).  I am having a few related problems displaying compounds both in and outside of equations.  The mhchem package is great until I encounter decimal values within a compounds formula (as shown below).  What I need is for the compound to be displayed in normal (non-italicized) type.  There are four lines in the body below that illustrate my issues.  The first line results in the compound being italicized.  The second illustrates a related problem, that being that the portion enclosed in parenthesis is italicized.  The third is how the `\ce` command handles a decimal point.  The fourth shows a workaround for using the `\ce` command.  The third and fourth lines also result in the equation number being flush with the equation instead of over on the right margin -- why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} X_{Li_{2}(SO_{4})_{0.5}} \end{equation}

Li_{2}(SO_{4})_{0.5}

\begin{equation} X_{\ce{Li2(SO4)0.5} \end{equation}

\begin{equation} X_{\ce{Li2(SO4)_{0.5}} \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I've started looking into perhaps doing some Lua or modifying `mhchem.sty`.  I've also tried using `\text{}`, `\textnormal{}`, etc. within my equation but apparently I haven't done it correctly yet.  I am not terribly experienced with `LaTeX` and was hoping that somebody with more experience than me might step forward with something tidy.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: @cgnieder: OK. I'll delete my comments shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't working as it stands:
the second line is not in math mode or inside `\ce` so `_` must issue an error.

```
Li_{2}(SO_{4})_{0.5}
```

In the third and fourth line the groups are not balenced but miss a `}`. After correcting this:

```
\begin{equation} X_{\ce{Li2(SO4)0.5}} \end{equation}

\begin{equation} X_{\ce{Li2(SO4)_{0.5}}} \end{equation}
```

the behaviour of the third is documented `mhchem` behaviour to display adducts so the forth is not a workaround but the way to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{Li2(SO4)_{0.5}}

Adduct: \ce{Na2SO4.10H2O}

\begin{equation}
 X_{\ce{Li2(SO4)_{0.5}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively one can use (my own) [`chemformula`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

\ch{Li2(SO4)_{0.5}}

Adduct: \ch{Na2SO4 * 10 H2O}

\begin{equation}
 X_{\ch{Li2(SO4)_{0.5}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: missed braces.  i feel dumb!!  i had worked out enclosing all my subscripted numbers in math mode last week before I started using mhchem and had since forgotten that.  brain is just cooked a bit too much I guess.  thanks very much for helping me.

Comment: btw, I looked over chemmacros a bit and I like them better.  I'll bring it up with the customer and see if they have a preferences.

Comment: @Huliax Note that the syntax of `chemmacros` is different in details. Also it is more strict about its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
\ce{$3.043$ Fe2O3}
```

just use maths-escape mode, using `$$` to embrace the number. There should not be any white spaces between `$` and the number otherwise the compiling would go wrongly, though this is not the case in normal equations.

Ref: http://tumutanzi.com/archives/11825